# Grouping 'islands' in MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, sql, gaps-and-islands

I'm struggling to solve a 'gaps and island' problem that I thought would be simple.

Turn this result set:

```
7:18    WORK
7:19    WORK
7:20    WORK
7:29    BREAK
7:30    BREAK
7:31    WORK
7:32    WORK
7:33    IDLE
7:34    IDLE
7:35    IDLE
7:36    IDLE
```

To this:

```
from_timestamp  until_timestamp status  records_in_island
7:18    7:24    WORK    6
7:29    7:32    BREAK   3
7:31    7:32    WORK    2
7:33    7:36    IDLE    4
```

Or basically to show:

- timestamp of the start and end of each island
- number of records in each island

Here's a dbfiddle with the data:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=a15cc8325ef4bc743df3208f8f328b9a

I couldn't find any solution in the gaps and islands solutions I found. I'm using MySQL 5.7 (due to AWS Aurora limitation) so can't use WITH or other MySQL 8.0 syntax.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: how come the first column for 2nd row in desired output is 7:27, shouldn't it be 7:29 ?

Comment: Thanks Harsh - you're 100% correct - I noticed this error when I created the dbfiddle. Thanks for noticing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way is to use variables inside the `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT event, MIN(event_time) AS event_time, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM (
  SELECT 
    CASE WHEN @e = event THEN @c ELSE @c := @c + 1 END AS id,
    event_time,  @e := event AS event
  FROM events, (SELECT @c := 0, @e := '') vars
  ORDER BY event_time
) t  
GROUP BY id, event
ORDER BY event_time
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=07f7b6f4d31c2b4395bb71a91c6b4ff7)

But since `MySQL 8` setting user variables within expressions is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.

Comment: User14717238 - you're amazing.

Comment: I'm sure you're happily employed, but if you're considering a new opportunity, please let us know. If you email jobs@getclue.com I'll get it directly.

PS your elegant solution worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the simplest method is to use `where` to filter out values where the "previous" value has the same value of column 2.  Assuming the values are date/time values and aligned on exactly one minute:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (select t2.status
              from test t2
              where t2.timestamp < t.timestamp
              order by t2.timestamp desc
              limit 1
             ) as prev_status
      from test t
     ) t
where not prev_status <=> status;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6d37b12e18b446d1b9cfc4a4fc363543) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks Gordron. I just edited the question and added a db fiddle, as I wasn't able to make your query work.
Here's the fiddle:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=a15cc8325ef4bc743df3208f8f328b9a

Comment: @Clueless . . . I fixed the fiddle so the timestamps are unique, modified the query to correspond to your data model, and added the fiddle to the answer.