# how to find consecutive day for login

Tags: mysql, sql, date, subquery, mysql-5.7

there is table in my database (MySQL 5.7.36),I try to find consecutive day
with condition

if consecutive day > 7

consecutive day will be set zero

| DATE_SERV |
| --- |
| 2022-01-01 |
| 2022-01-02 |
| 2022-01-03 |
| 2022-01-05 |
| 2022-01-06 |
| 2022-01-09 |
| 2022-01-10 |
| 2022-01-11 |

my actually expect table is

| DATE_SERV | day_consecutive |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 |
| 2022-01-02 | 2 |
| 2022-01-03 | 3 |
| 2022-01-05 | 1 |
| 2022-01-06 | 2 |
| 2022-01-09 | 1 |
| 2022-01-10 | 2 |
| 2022-01-11 | 3 |
| 2022-01-12 | 4 |
| 2022-01-13 | 5 |
| 2022-01-14 | 6 |
| 2022-01-15 | 7 |
| 2022-01-16 | 1 |
| 2022-01-17 | 2 |

Comment: which RDBMS are you using MySQL,SQL Server,....

Comment: I using MySQL...................

Comment: What version of MySQL? 5.x has different capabilities than 8.x

Comment: version mySQL  5.7.36

Comment: mysql 5.7 has no window functions so check again

Comment: thank you so much. I just try on local MySQL.But, I have to develop on my server

Comment: I don't follow. Are you saying you're running MySQL 8.x locally, but your server is running 5.7.x?

Comment: I running MySQL 8.0.20 locally, but my server is running 5.7.36

Comment: Any chance of upgrading? It'd be much easier with the window function support in 8.x. Unfortunately I'm not sure how with MySQL 5.x...

Comment: The only thing I've found is using the old @ variables hack https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65847509/grouping-islands-in-mysql-5-7  but be aware of the behavior risks and limitations (https://stackoverflow.com/a/54997037/8895292)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this up before, thinking you were using MySQL 8.x (which supports [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html), unfortunately 5.x does not). Anyway, just posting it in case it's useful to someone else ...

---

You can adapt the approach from this blog [Gaps and Islands Across Date Ranges](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/gaps-and-islands-across-date-ranges). First identify the "islands" or groups of consecutive dates

```
SELECT
        DATE_SERV
        , SUM( IF( DATEDIFF(DATE_SERV, Prev_Date) = 1, 0, 1) ) OVER(
                   ORDER BY DATE_SERV 
        )  AS DateGroup_Num
FROM
      (
         SELECT DATE_SERV
                , LAG(DATE_SERV,1) OVER (
                       ORDER BY DATE_SERV
                ) AS Prev_Date
         FROM   YourTable
      ) grp
```

Which produces this result:

| DATE_SERV | DateGroup_Num |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 |
| 2022-01-02 | 1 |
| 2022-01-03 | 1 |
| 2022-01-05 | 2 |
| 2022-01-06 | 2 |
| 2022-01-09 | 3 |
| 2022-01-10 | 3 |
| 2022-01-11 | 3 |

Then use a conditional SUM(...) to find the earliest date per group, and display the number of consecutive days since that date:

```
SELECT 
       t.DATE_SERV
       , DATEDIFF( 
            t.DATE_SERV
            , MIN(t.DATE_SERV) OVER( 
                  PARTITION BY t.DateGroup_Num 
                  ORDER BY t.DATE_SERV 
             )
        ) +1 AS Consecutive_Days
FROM ( 
        SELECT
               DATE_SERV
              , SUM( IF( DATEDIFF(DATE_SERV, Prev_Date) = 1, 0, 1) ) OVER(
                    ORDER BY DATE_SERV 
                )  AS DateGroup_Num
        FROM
        (
                SELECT DATE_SERV
                       , LAG(DATE_SERV,1) OVER (
                            ORDER BY DATE_SERV
                         ) AS Prev_Date
                FROM   YourTable
        ) grp
    ) t
```

**Results:**

| DATE_SERV | Consecutive_Days |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 |
| 2022-01-02 | 2 |
| 2022-01-03 | 3 |
| 2022-01-05 | 1 |
| 2022-01-06 | 2 |
| 2022-01-09 | 1 |
| 2022-01-10 | 2 |
| 2022-01-11 | 3 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=29a3e772311cbc8f3393923379ad55c8)*